# Adding new user to LDAP using PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to integrate two systems between Joomla3 and SugarCRM CE 6.5. User password management is done by LDAP so both users in Joomla3 and SugarCRM will use this authentication system.

However what we need to is to get SugarCRM to be the system where the users are created, as I dont want the person in charge of creating new accounts to work with LDAP.

We are creating a logic_hook before save function under the Users module, so when a new user is created in SugarCRM

1) Checks that it does not exists in LDAP - DONE

2) If it does not exists we launch this before_save function to create it - FAILING

This is the function we are calling (it receives the user bean that is being saved), and I dont know why it is failing at line ldap_add... however do not why, or even do not know how to debug the error, as only the "FALSE" value is returned.

Any ideas please??

```
function Add_LDAP ($user)
{
    $ldap_host = 'localhost';
        $base_dn = 'CN='.$user->user_name.',DC=regiac,DC=org';
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal($base_dn);
        //Preparamos el usuario para crearlo
        $info["givenName"]=$user->first_name;
        $info["sn"]=$user->last_name;
        $info["uid"]=$user->user_name;
        $info["homeDirectory"]="/home/";
        $info["mail"]=$user->email1;
        $info["displayName"]= $user->first_name." ".$user->last_name;
        $info["departmentNumber"]=$user->id;
        $info["cn"] =$user->user_name;
        $info["userPassword"]=$user->user_hash;
        $info["objectclass"][0] = "top";
        $info["objectclass"][1] = "person";
        $info["objectclass"][2] = "inetOrgPerson";
        $info["objectclass"][3] = "organizationalPerson";



        $ldap_user  = "CN=admin,DC=regiac,DC=org";
        $ldap_pass = "passw";

        //First: Connect to  LDAP Server
        $connect = ldap_connect( $ldap_host, $ldap_port)
         or $GLOBALS['log']->fatal(">>Could not connect to LDAP server to add user<<");
        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

//Login to LDAP
        $bind = ldap_bind($connect, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass)
           or $GLOBALS['log']->fatal(">>Could not bind to $ldap_host to add user<<");

// Adding new user - Here it is where it fails

    $add = ldap_add($connect, $base_dn, $info)
      or $GLOBALS['log']->fatal(">>Not able to load user <<");

// Close connection
       ldap_close($connect);

   // Return value of operation

        return $add;




}
```

Comment: what the error message on server logs?

Comment: what the message on $GLOBALS['log']?

Comment: Hi the error message in the log (the one I write) is:>>Not able to load user <<, nothing else, no exception or error returned. The Connect and Bind works fine, and I have other php method to search for users from LDAP that works fine... but not this one to add the user in the LDAP.

Comment: change log verbosity. The error must appears on log.

Comment: but I find one error. The atribute homeDirectory is not present on definition of listed objectClasses, remove it to test.

Answer (score 0):

The atribute homeDirectory is not permited by any objectClasses.